# How can I detect if a login is suspicious?

Tags: security, authentication

I want to detect whether or not an account sign in is suspicious, like [Google is doing it](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6063333?hl=en). How can I achieve that, or what resources should I look at?

Scenario: My login credentials are stolen at yet another Yahoo breach, and a hacker is using those to sign into a service. I want to detect that this user is not the real user, for example, by using the location of the sign in ip address.

Comment: @lkdhruw — Google show that when they consider activity to be suspicious. They don't generally do it to detect suspicious activity in the first place.

Comment: Recaptcha does not prevent a hacker from using my stolen access credentials to sign into my account

Comment: This is a really broad topic. Checkout the Security Diversification strategies detailed by Peter Gutmann in [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf). The trick is, its *not* a Boolean, Yes/No answer. You develop metrics or a weighted score, and allow the login if it meets a threshold. You adjust the threshold based on your risk adversity.

Comment: Device tracking could be the solution, provided the user had previously used the service with the cookie recorded in user PC.

Answer (score 5):

Suspicious behaviour if the login is from

1. A browser you've never used before. For example, you could set a long-term signed cookie after successful login. If someone tries to login without said cookie...
2. A different OS or browser brand. You always use Windows and Chrome. Now someone is logging in with Kali Linux and Firefox...
3. A different IP or ISP. IPs can change pretty frequently but you'll often use the same ISP at work or home
4. A different geographical location. Say you've historically always signed in from California and Oregon. A login from India is then suspicious
5. A different time of day than normal for you. Say you always sign in between 9 AM and 5 PM, but someone tries to sign in at 3 AM, that's suspicious

None of these is super suspicious on their own but may be in combination